# How to run an application on a headless Ubuntu?

Tags: ssh, headless

I have an Intel NUC running 3.13.11.6; and I have written an application that runs some simple data polling (cpu, memory usage, disk usage etc ...).  The NUC is headless, so I connect via SSH (putty) and can execute the program.

My issue is that I need the program to run for days; and if I close the putty session, the process is killed.

I do not have cron on the system, or some way to remote execute the application (that I am aware of).

*** edit - some recommendations for using screen and tmux were great, however I am learning this is a custom implementation of Ubuntu and these are not available.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to run an application on a headless Ubuntu system and not have the process killed when the ssh session disconnects?

Appreciate any help!

Thank you,

Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using nohup:

```
$ nohup ./example.sh &
```

This will run your process in the background and won't be terminated when you exit your shell (logout). It will write output to a file called nohup.out.

Comment: This resolves the issue.  As this is a light install of Ubuntu, many of the tools normally available were not.  I was not aware of nohup.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
screen ./example.sh
```

will start your process inside an own shell. You can detach from this shell by holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and pressing <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Now you can close your SSH connection and the process will keep running. You can also reconnect via SSH and run

```
screen -r
```

to get back to your process